# PhP update code on test code won't execute

Tags: php

I have looked all over at other places of Stack Overflow and not found an answer. I might just be silly and not seeing it but =( This isn't working.

```
    if($upd_stmt = $mysqli4->prepare("UPDATE `tblUserInformation` SET fldfirstphone=?, fldaltphone=?, fldSkype=?  WHERE flduserID=?"))
    {       
        //Bind parameters to found ID
        $upd_stmt->bind_param('sss', $phone1, $phone2, $NA, $id);
        //Update the field
        if($upd_stmt->execute())
        {
        echo 'update successful!';
        }
```

I have tried so many things and even echo'd it all, I get all the right information out of each of my variables to bind, but it just won't execute. It goes down to

```
else if(! $upd_stmt->execute())
        {
            //Failure to update
            echo 'Update failed';
        }
```

Is there something wrong with my prepare statement?

I have made mysqli4, I know it is not needed, but this is still just test code! I just want it to work.

Comment: `'sss', $phone1, $phone2, $NA, $id` 3 then 4?

Comment: I am sorry, Jon, I see now what you were trying to say, haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$upd_stmt->bind_param('sssd', $phone1, $phone2, $NA, $id);

Comment: OH GOD, Did I really miss that? Haha I feel so silly!

Comment: You might want to elaborate your answer, what did OP do wrong? What is your answer changing? Why does your answer work?

Comment: I feel very silly I did not see this, however it works now. I might just be needing glasses =) Thank you though, this will be set as an answer, I just hope you will update it for others who might be having the same eye problems!